# Get cell value LSTM C++

Tags: нейронные-сети

Как получить значение ячейки LSTM в C++ для оценки ???

Как получить выходное значение скрытого слоя (не только LSTM), например, есть 3 скрытых слоя, как получить выходное значение 2 слоя ???

```
pair = LSTMPComponentWithSelfStabilization<float>(
classifierRoot,
{ 2 },
{ 300 },
pastValueRecurrenceHook,
pastValueRecurrenceHook,
device);

classifierRoot = pair.first;
```

Как из "classifierRoot" получить "pair" или "c" (ceil) ???